# How to exclude file types when copying recursively in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a windows directory X with subdirectories x_1...x_100. Each one of the subdirectories x_i (i=1..100) contains a different data file (of various names) as well as an additional file called "annotation.txt" that I do not need.

I wish to copy all of the data files in x_1...x_100 into a new directory Y, to the exclusion of "annotation.txt", because otherwise I get prompted with 100 overwrite questions.

The syntax I used for the recursive copy is:

```
for /r "C:<path to X> %x in (*) do move "%x" "C:<path to y>
```

What do I need to add in order to copy all files except "annotation.txt" (or, more generally, all files except for those containing some wild card string)?

Comment: Use `IF` statement as follows: `… do IF /I NOT "%~nxx"=="annotation.txt" move "%x" "C:<path to y>"` or use `/Y` switch which should _suppress prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file_ `… do move /Y "%x" "C:<path to y>"`

Comment: The /Y argument seems to be the simplest solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `robocopy`. I do not know if you want to MOVE directories or only files. See `robocopy /?` for details about using `/MOV` or `/MOVE`. The `/XF` parameter allows exclusion of files.

```
robocopy C:\source\dir C:\destination\dir * /S /E /MOV /XF annotation.txt
```

**Update:**

How about using PowerShell?

```
Get-ChildItem -Files -Recurse -Path 'C:\source\dir' -Exclude "annotation.txt" |
    ForEach-Ohject { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\destination\dir' -WhatIf }
```

Comment: I only want to move the files, so that I have all of the data tables in a single directory rather than having each in its own subdirectory along with a redundant data file. I haven't worked with robocopy before, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, robocopy would copy the directory structure as well. Have a look at `forfiles /?`.

Comment: what if I want to exclude multiple file extensions? `*.pdf`, `*.txt`?

Comment: @Sisir, please review the help information using the command `help Get-ChildItem -Full`. The `-Exclude` parameter is an array allowing multiple path qualifiers. `-Exclude @('*.pdf', '*.txt')`